# Getting this error UNIQUE constraint failed: store_order.id

Tags: python, django

Whenever i try to update an order I get this error,

Here is my model:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    ('Processing', 'Processing'),
    ('Picked', 'Picked'),
    ('Shipped', 'Shipped'),
    ('Completed', 'Completed'),
)


class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product")
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(datetime.datetime.today, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, default="Unpaid", unique=True)
    order_status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=CHOICES, null=True, blank=True, default="In Review")
    payment_method = models.ForeignKey(
        PaymentMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    total = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.quantity * self.price
        return super().save(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

I don't know why I am getting this kind of error can someone please explain why I am getting its error and how can I solve this issue.

Here is my order view:

```
class Checkout(View):
    def post(self, request):
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        address = request.POST.get('address')
        cart = request.session.get('cart')
        customer = request.session.get('customer')
        products = Product.get_products_id(list(cart.keys()))

        for product in products:
            order = Order(customer=Customer(id=customer['id']), product=product, fname=fname,
                          price=product.price, phone=phone, address=address, quantity=cart.get(str(product.id)))

            order.save()

        request.session['cart'] = {}

        return redirect('user_orders')
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Your page for adding new checkout is broken, because it doesn’t
associate new checkout with any particular user. If you try adding a new checkout,
you’ll see the error message IntegrityError along with NOT NULL constraint
failed: store_order.id Django’s saying you can’t create a new
checkout without specifying a value for the checkout’s owner field.

Can you tell, what you're trying to do ? You want to add new checkout ?

**Then try to use this :-**

**order.customer = request.customer**

**order.save()**

Comment: i wanted to update the order like a customer wants to cancel his order I want to update the status to cancel or he wants to change his product quantity.if I update the order I get this error

Comment: I think , you didn't specify a particular user for update the orders.
Where are you options that you want to update or not in views.py ?

Comment: its not in views.py i am trying to update these in django admin panel

Comment: I've updated my answer, and try to use it.

Comment: There was a typo, now i have updated again

Comment: no its same Bro. i am getting the same error

Comment: i dont have User model i have only customer model

Comment: what could be the solution to this problem ??? @Program

Comment: Django’s saying you can’t update a new checkout without specifying a value for the checkout’s owner field.

Comment: Which is your user instance that you define that this user is ordered some items ?

Comment: customer = request.session.get('customer') here it is

Comment: try this :-

order = request.customer
order.save()